# Excel VBA: Using variable in loop to define a Range next to the current cell

Tags: vba, excel

In *WorksheetA* I have a column name *Config*,

and I want to look up for a specific values, and if this value is found, the copy the respective configuration from another worksheet named *WorksheetB* (that is basically an index/list of different configurations)

So, in *WorksheetA* is found the value "J" then the range(D20:G31) will be equal to the values of *WorksheetB* range(B15:E26) and so on until all the values in this column in *WorksheetA* be verified.

My obviously wrong code so far is this

```
Public Sub CheckIndex()
     Sheets("Worksheet_A").Select
     ' Find the last row of data
     FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     ' Loop through each row
     For x = 2 To FinalRow
     ' Decide if to copy based on column C
    ThisValue = Cells(x, 3).Value
        ' SinglePath Configuration
         If ThisValue = "J" Then
             Sheets("Worksheet_A").Range("D" & x & ":G" & x + 11).Value = Sheets("Worksheet_B").Range("B15:E26").Value

         ElseIf ThisValue = "C" Then
              Sheets("Worksheet_A").Range("D" & x & ":G" & x + 11).Value = Sheets("Worksheet_B").Range("B3:E14").Value
         End If

Next x
```

End Sub

So is there a any way to use the value of the variable in a loop to define a range next to the current position?
My code is so bad that I should fell bad about it? jk (I already know its bad)

I've only recently started using VBA, therefore I have few experience writing macros. So Thanks in advance for all the responses

Comment: try `x = 5
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B15:E26").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & x)`

Comment: @ZAT Yeah that works Great thanks!!! (btw as this is my first question: How do I set it answered?)

Comment: @Zegat: Either you propose ZAT to move his comment into an answer, otherwise you just accept your own answer, and surely upvote ZAT's comment

Comment: @Zegad glad it worked. follow what iDevlop said. Upvote my comment above and mark what you posted as answer below.

Comment: @ZAT I´m unnable to upvote your comment (Ik is clicking in the arrow next to your comment) but somehow its not available, I don't know if is a constrain related to me being a new user... :/

But if you want, copy my answer (I will delete mine) and mark yours as the right one, to be able to retribute you back for your help.

Comment: @Zegad no problem. Upvoting your answer for the generous proposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ZAT propose  the final code is:

```
Public Sub CheckIndex()

Sheets("Worksheet_A").Select
' Find the last row of data
FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
' Loop through each row
For x = 5 To FinalRow
    ' Decide if to copy based on column C
    ThisValue = Cells(x, 3).Value
' SinglePath Configuration
    If ThisValue = "J" Then

        Worksheets("Worksheet_B").Range("B15:E26").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Worksheet_A").Range("D" & x)

    ElseIf ThisValue = "C" Then

        Worksheets("Worksheet_B").Range("B3:E14").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Worksheet_A").Range("D" & x)
```